# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

I am getting following error

```
Cannot implicitly convert type
'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>' to
'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'
```

I tried reading similar questions on stack overflow but didn't find a solution.
My code is as below

```
var head =     
    from key in doc.Descendants("Header").Descendants("Article")
    select new 
     {
       value = (key.Value == String.Empty ?
       from q in doc.Descendants("Header").Descendants("Article") select q.Value : from a in doc.Descendants("Header").Descendants("Article") 
      select a.Attribute("DefaultValue").Value)

    };
List<string> hsourceFields = head.ToList();
```

If the value of xml node is empty I am reading the default value specified for that xml node

```
<Header>      
<Article>News</Article>
<Article DefaultValue ="Sport"></Article>    
</Header>
```

I want to be able to return a List which I am not able to by getting the error.

[image]

Comment: What if you change List<string> to List<T>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your code was getting a `List<AnonType{value = List<string>}>` instead of a `List<string>`

I think you want something like this that will select the text from an article or if that is empty it will take the value of the DefaultValue attribute. Note this doesn't handle when there is no text and no attribute.

```
var head =     
    from key in doc.Descendants("Header").Descendants("Article")
    select      
      string.IsNullOrEmpty(key.Value) ?
          key.Attribute("DefaultValue").Value :
          key.Value;
List<string> hsourceFields = head.ToList();
```

Or a slightly abbreviated version that uses xpath and method chains

```
var hsourceFields = doc.XPathSelectElements("/Header/Article")
     .Select (x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Value) ?
        x.Attribute("DefaultValue").Value :
        x.Value).ToList()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you read the error it exactly tells you the problem. You want a string list however you have a list of anonymous objects. Instead use

```
var hSouceFields = head.ToList()
```

Comment: I tried this and above is a print screen of what I get. I don't get a debug error if I do so, but the list is not actually filled with values. I think I need some cast or sth that I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the way I was reading xml nodes to

```
var head = (from k in doc.Descendants("Header")
            select k).ToList();

List<String> hsourceFields = new List<string>();

 foreach (var t in head.Descendants("Article"))
 {
     if (t.Attribute("DefaultValue") != null)
      {
          hsourceFields.Add(t.Attribute("DefaultValue").Value);
      }
      else
           hsourceFields.Add(t.Value);
}
```

Not proud of my solution though.

Comment: `from k in doc.Descendants("Header") select k` can be simplified to just `doc.Descendants("Header")`. And that `ToList()` is not necessary here.